# Multiple Anchor tags have single click event to each

Tags: jquery

I created anchor tags `<a>` surrounded by `<li>` tags dynamically and all are appended to `<ul>`.Then with click event of each anchor tags ajax request is made to controller and some data is get from it. Now I want each anchor tags to be clicked by once if any anchor tag is clicked twice than it should be disable or unclicked so that ajax call not made again Now the problem is how I check the click count of anchor `<a>` tag.

My html Code is here:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">

</ul>
```

And script part:

```
for (var c in data.categoryTypes)   
{                                                                                                
    $('< a/>').attr('href','#'+data.ABC[c]).attr('data-toggle', "pill").text (data.ABC[c]).wrap('< li id='+c+'/>').parent().appendTo('.nav.nav-pills');
}
```

Click event is here:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function (e) 
{
    var categoryValue = $(this).text(); 
    alert(categoryValue);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to add a class like disabled after clicking the link and remove the class after the ajax call

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li:not("disabled")', function (e)
{
        $(this).addClass('disabled'); //add the class
        var categoryValue = $(this).text(); 
        alert(categoryValue);
        e.preventDefault();
       //do a ajax call, In ajax success remove the class disabled. 
          $(this).removeClass('disabled'); 
  });
```

Comment: The link is still clickable twice and e.preventDefault(); is not working

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` will prevent the navigation of anchor tag href link...